# Spinning a picture at a certain speed slowing to stop like a prize wheel

Tags: c#

I have a game where I need a wheel to spin, but I want to be able to set when I want it to stop which is fine if I can figure out how to slow it down without using a timer like I am then I can handle that part.

what I have so  far is a rotateimage function which I found and using a timer (changing the interval) to slow it down.  What I'm asking is in winforms is there a better way to do this because I have to let it spin faster a few times then slow down then stop.

I have found help for this is many different languages but not C# win forms.  I wanted to know if it is possible.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    image = new Bitmap(@"C:\wheel.png");
    Wheel1.Image = (Bitmap)image.Clone();
    wheelspeed1 = wheelspeed1 + 5;
    angle = wheelspeed1;
    RotateImage(Wheel1, image, angle);
    Wheel1.Refresh();
    if (timer1.Interval < 150)
    {
        timer1.Interval++;
    }
    else
        timer1.Enabled = false;
}

public static Bitmap RotateImage(Image image, float angle)
{
    return RotateImage(image, new PointF((float)image.Width / 2, (float)image.Height / 2), angle);
}

public static Bitmap RotateImage(Image image, PointF offset, float angle)
{
    if (image == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("image");

    Bitmap rotatedBmp = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height);
    rotatedBmp.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(rotatedBmp);

    g.TranslateTransform(offset.X, offset.Y);

    g.RotateTransform(angle);

    g.TranslateTransform(-offset.X, -offset.Y);

    g.DrawImage(image, new PointF(0, 0));

    return rotatedBmp;
}
```

This makes it spin and slow down and stop but its a really bad way of doing it I know that. Also, it doesn't really allow me to let it spin fast for a while before slowing and stopping.

Comment: Seems that the wheelspeed should be a function of time.

Comment: Clearly you'll need a smarter way to increment the wheelspeed1 variable, nothing drastic.  You are sloppy with your bitmaps, I'd just use Graphics.RotateTransform() in a Paint event handler instead.  Other than that, I don't see a question that needs to be answered.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to spin at top speed for a bit before starting to slow down, create a counter. Then start spinning fast and decrement the counter at every interval. When that counter gets to 0, start increasing the interval.

So, something like:

```
private int _fastSpinCounter = 50; // spin fast for this many intervals
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    image = new Bitmap(@"C:\wheel.png");
    Wheel1.Image = (Bitmap)image.Clone();
    // not sure why you're increasing the rotation angle here
    wheelspeed1 = wheelspeed1 + 5;
    angle = wheelspeed1;
    RotateImage(Wheel1, image, angle);
    Wheel1.Refresh();
    if (_fastSpinCounter > 0)
    {
        --_fastSpinCounter;
    else if (timer1.Interval < 150)
    {
        timer1.Interval++;
    }
    else
        timer1.Enabled = false;
}
```

On a related note, you really don't need to be loading that image at every timer tick. You could just load the bitmap once and keep it cached. As it is, you're failing to call `Dispose` on the image, which could cause you to have resource problems if the timer ticks especially fast.