# How to animate rotating bitmap in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, bitmap

I'm trying to animate a bitmap in a way I will see it rotating fast until it slowly stops rotating.
I tried to use "invokerequired" but it did not show me the progress of the rotation, only the result in which I see all angles instead of only the final one.

```
private void GameBoardPanel_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    bool move = PickOrDropPiece(e);

    Point piecePos = getBoardPointLocation(e);

    if (move)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(x => Run(piecePos)));
    }

}

private void Run(Point pos)
{
    const int Max = 1000;

    for (int i = 0; i < Max; i++)
    {
        Update(i , pos);
    }
}
private void Update(int i, Point pos)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action<int, Point>(Update), i , pos);
    }
    else
    {
        RotateImage(GameBoard.GetBitmap(pos), i * 90 % 360, pos);
    }
}
```

How can I do it?
Maybe some other way?
Please help with a code example.

Comment: It's not a good idea to run `Update` from a loop. Look into `Timer` or some other way of running the function on a time interval.

Comment: we cant use Timers due to teacher constraints.. :/

Comment: The problem with what you have right now is that the loop will finish in a blink of an eye (even if you increase your `Max`). What you need to do is slow it down. The best thing to do is run the function every X milliseconds. Another option is `Thread.Sleep()`.

Comment: you might want to look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029555/spinning-a-picture-at-a-certain-speed-slowing-to-stop-like-a-prize-wheel

Comment: and this one http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/38199/rotate-to-a-set-degree-then-stop-unity

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
 class and it's `Elapsed` event.

You can do something like this:

```
void Update
{
     Update logic here
}

Timer UpdateTimer = new Timer();

void Initialize
{
     UpdateTimer.Elapsed += Update;
}

void RotateStart
{
     UpdateTimer.Start();
}

void RotateStop
{
     UpdateTimer.Stop();
}
```